# Импорт данных в БД из нескольких csv файлов

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Требуется заполнить в БД (Postgresql) таблицу сгенерированными данными.
Всего около 500 млн записей.

Данные я генерирую самостоятельно в csv вида:
123,stroka,456,t,,,f,,

И из-за того что всего данные занимают около 140 Gb я разделил их на 40 файлов, каждый из которых приходится загружать вручную через импорт данных Dbeaver. Если загружать файл большего размера, то возникают ошибки, поэтому делю на файлы по 3.5 Gb.

Доступа на сервер с БД у меня нет.

**Существует ли софт для пакетной загрузки данных в БД? В идеале для параллельного импорта из нескольких файлов.**

Пробовал через создание задачи в Dbeaver указывать несколько файлов, но после загрузки первого из них падает с нехваткой памяти.

Comment: С питоном дружите?

Comment: @Namerek знаком немного. Разобраться смогу.

Comment: Тогда берите `psycopg2` и из нее `execute_batch` Если хотите пример, добавьте образец данных в вопрос. Или можно сформировать `json` и разобрать его в таблицу в `postgresql`

Comment: Или вот здесь почитать попробуйте https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-import-csv/